# Transit visa in Dubai for Philippine passport

Tags: transit, layovers, emirates

I hold a Philippine passport but a green card holder/permanent resident of the United States. I will be traveling to Maldives from the U.S.  I have an 8 hr layover in Dubai. Do I need a visa to leave the airport and tour the city?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a layover of 8h or more, you are eligible to get a transit visa on arrival that is valid for 96 hours from the time of entry.

Source: http://www.dubai.com/v/visa_requirements/